# "some chapters of it" vs "some of its chapters"

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

which one should i use and where? for example:

> in order to shorten the book we have omitted **some of its chapters**

or

> in order to shorten the book we have omited **some chapters of it**?

Answer (score 2):

How about neither? I’d suggest “In order to shorten the book, we have omitted some chapters.” The meaning is clear from context.

Answer (score 0):

A native English speaker would prefer your first version as it sounds more natural.

> In order to shorten the book we have omitted some of its chapters.

The second version is still grammatically correct.
You could also say

> In order to shorten the book some chapters have been omitted.